# Customizing a new page used for blog posts with Avada theme

Tags: posts, templates, blog

I'm using the avada theme for my website and I created a page called 'My Blog' and in reading settings I set this to display recent posts. It works, but when I created the page I selected a custom blog template I made in my theme folder and it seems to ignore it.

I've looked at the heirarchy of templates but I still don't know what to do here. My theme has no front-page.php, only page and index and I don't want to mess with other pages settings, just my blog posts page.

Comment: If you look at the [diagram](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) of the WordPress template hierarchy, you'd see that the Blog Posts index page will try to look for `home.php` before it defaults to the index template (`index.php`). So you'll need to copy the code in the custom blog template and use the code in `home.php`. Or you could use filters like `home_template` or `template_include` filter to force loading of the custom page template.

Comment: so I should copy index.php into a new file called home.fphp?

Comment: Yes, you can try that.